# Ubuntu gives error while update

Tags: apt, updates, repository

When I try to update using  `apt-get update` give above error. I don't what causes this error, do you have any idea how can I fix this ?

> W: GPG error:
>   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04
>   Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
>   public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886 W:
>
> The
>   repository
>   'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04
>   Release' is not signed. N: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details.

Comment: Are you using any package/service of OpenSUSE?

Comment: @Kulfy it seems so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to [visit corresponding *software.opensuse.org* OpenSuSe site](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=arc-theme) and then follow instructions from it for the Ubuntu:

> **You can add the repository key to apt. Keep in mind that the owner of the key may distribute updates, packages and repositories that your system will trust (more information). To add the key, run:**
>
> ```
> wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key
> sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

Also note that OpenSuse build service page for this repository is located on [build.opensuse.org](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:Horst3180#).