# Ubuntu gives error when trying to update

Tags: apt, updates, themes

When I try to update using  `apt-get update` I get the following errors (which are incresing in amount while I'm following some tutos found here).

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 5A7D1D38BEB6D886 home:Horst3180 OBS Project <home:Horst3180@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Horst3180.list:1
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Horst3180.list:1
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Horst3180.list:1
```

This [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091607/ubuntu-gives-error-while-update) gave me the last three Ws in the above list and I also tried to update the expired signatures (where I did not succed).

This is what I get when I run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

I have the following files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

```
arc-theme.list           home:Horst3180.list
arc-theme.list.save      home:Horst3180.list.save
google-chrome.list       sunderme-ubuntu-texstudio-bionic.list
google-chrome.list.save  sunderme-ubuntu-texstudio-bionic.list.save
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gives error while update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091607/ubuntu-gives-error-while-update)

Comment: @N0rbert The link in my question is exactly what you are asking me to try. After doing that I've got the last three errors.

Comment: There's a problem with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or an issue with that PPA. That's what the errors are saying.  Please edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.  Are you still using the software associated with that PPA?

Comment: @Nmath Done! It seems it is the theme used in my Ubuntu's version. I am new on Ubuntu, so I am unsure about your question.

Comment: that PPA isn't in the default location, but it's that "Horst3180" PPA that is causing problems.  Do you have files in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?  (FYI PPA is a pretty insecure way of installing software, I would never recommend adding a PPA for a theme)  See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed/

Comment: @Nmath I added the files in the question.

Comment: I suggest the solutions on  the question on "How can PPAs be removed".  Removing those PPAs from your sources should resolve the issue.  As a last resort you can copy the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as a backup, and then delete them, then try to run `sudo apt update` again.  If removing those files breaks something you can restore them/ move them back.

Comment: @Nmath That made the trick. Thanks!!